# Building and starting a web role in Visual Studio with a specific URL

Tags: visual-studio, iis, azure

I have an Azure service containing a web role. Both configured to run on IIS Server locally. I would like to build/deploy and start the web role in a specific URL in Visual Studio. It always ends up in addresses using 127.0.0.1 even I specify what project URL is in the project configuration. Is there any way to change this something like dev.xxx.com?

Answer (score 0):

You're running through the local emulator I assume. As such, the URL project settings won't apply. Just like if you deploy it to the cloud, you'll need some type of DNS forwarder or alias.